# How to make a file so that it can be written only in my application but read-only for others?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, file-permissions

How can I create a file so that my application can write to it, rename it and delete it but others can read it only?. Not that this behavior must be retained after my application closes the file.

I have read this article 
[How to make a file read-write to a program but read-only/no access to non-admin users in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16313288/how-to-make-a-file-read-write-to-a-program-but-read-only-no-access-to-non-admin)
but it seems different from my situation.

Comment: Create a new user account, permission so only that user can modify the file, and run your application in the context of that user.

Comment: Permissions are granted to users rather than programs. So anything you come up with has to discriminate on user.

Comment: Not an answer, but you may want to watch [Cannot delete files even though I kill the handle](http://superuser.com/questions/1012228/cannot-delete-files-even-though-i-kill-the-handle) for the opposite angle.